# mediaplayer starts again and again in oncreate method

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, media-player

I have a `MediaPlayer` method which stream radio urls in `onCreate` method and when i start application, radio starts automatically. But when i rotate the screen radio starts again and again. And also "play" and "stop" buttons has `NullPointerException`.... error.

How can i solve this problem. I have already tried `savedInstanceBundle` but  i couldn't solve `NullPointerException`

Thank you.......

```
09-07 20:01:37.051: E/AndroidRuntime(2755): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-07 20:01:37.051: E/AndroidRuntime(2755): Process: com.kaproduction.myradio, PID: 2755
09-07 20:01:37.051: E/AndroidRuntime(2755): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-07 20:01:37.051: E/AndroidRuntime(2755):     at com.kaproduction.myradio.RadioActivity$1.onClick(RadioActivity.java:96)
09-07 20:01:37.051: E/AndroidRuntime(2755):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
09-07 20:01:37.051: E/AndroidRuntime(2755):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
09-07 20:01:37.051: E/AndroidRuntime(2755):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
09-07 20:01:37.051: E/AndroidRuntime(2755):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-07 20:01:37.051: E/AndroidRuntime(2755):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-07 20:01:37.051: E/AndroidRuntime(2755):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
09-07 20:01:37.051: E/AndroidRuntime(2755):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-07 20:01:37.051: E/AndroidRuntime(2755):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-07 20:01:37.051: E/AndroidRuntime(2755):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
09-07 20:01:37.051: E/AndroidRuntime(2755):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
09-07 20:01:37.051: E/AndroidRuntime(2755):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You need to show your code for `RadioActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

Start your mediaplayer in the onClick method of the "Play" Button.
For example:

```
public void onClick(){

    mediaplayer.start();

}
```

When you only start the mediaplayer in the onClick it won´t start when you open the app or rotate the phone.